# beeline can connect to jdbc:hive2:// but cannot connect to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, localhost, beeline

I am struggling with beeline connection to hive server. On my server (with name Sun, all the operation on this server),  In the hive folder, I can start beeline as `./bin/beeline` and then connect to hive: `!connect jdbc:hive2://`, then I am successfully connected to my hive and I can run hive-sql statement.

However, when I tried `./bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 -n hive -p mypassword`, I can not connect to hive directly, with error message "Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000"

I have tried to follow many posts (e.g. [beeline cannot connect to hive2server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772313/beeline-cannot-connect-to-hive2server), [Connecting to Hive using Beeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113323/connecting-to-hive-using-beeline), [Cannot connect to beeline hive2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240948/cannot-connect-to-beeline-hive2)) and I still can not find a solution. Why I can not connect with localhost:10000 (or its the IP of this Sun machine)?

Has anyone any idea why I have such error and how to solve it?

```
hadoop@Sun:/opt/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin$ ./bin/beeline
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl- 
2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Beeline version 3.1.2 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://: hive
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://: ****
21/06/14 23:02:10 [main]: WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Hive Session ID = ae2fb753-de6d-4522-b128-770b1c358c8b
21/06/14 23:02:11 [main]: WARN session.SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 3.1.2)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.2)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://> show databases;
OK
+----------------+
| database_name  |
+----------------+
| default        |
| testwimp       |
| wimp           |
+----------------+
3 rows selected (1.978 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: hive
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: ****
21/06/14 23:02:57 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://>
```

Comment: have you checked this one out? https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-JDBC-Could-not-open-client-transport-with-JDBC-Uri/td-p/101772

Comment: @linusRian, I saw this post, but I do not understand, changing the port number from 10000 to 100001?

Comment: It seems that this issue is an open bug that has not been completely solved:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14410

Comment: Not just the port number ,the url with transportMode and httpPath added to it,which is mentioned in the above link. jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;transportMode=http;httpPath=<http_endpoint>

Comment: @linusRian, I do not think this is the answer I am looking for. 1st, the httpPath/http_endpoint is not a property in the hive-site.xml file. 2nd, even I tried with such additional information, it still have same error message. 3rd, connecting directly by "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000" works for many other people without the need specifying the http mode. (I am sure on my Linux server, I am using ssl instead of http mode).

Comment: @`Yu Xiang` sorry that it couldn't solve the problem. Good to know that you were able to solve the problem with the answer listed below :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed answer here:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/93495333620/

In summary, check hiverserver2 is started and the port number 10000 is open.